# Change of Measures for Lévy-Processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes

If $X$ is a Lévy-Process on a filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_t, \mathbf P)$ and $Q$ an equivalent probability measure. Under which circumstances is $X$ also a Lévy-Process under $\mathbf Q$. Are there any good results?

I'd be grateful for any kind of help.

Thank you.

Comment: Proposition 9.8 in Cont & Tankov -- *Financial modelling with jump processes* gives the conditions for the two measures being equivalent